# Do we really need RPA for Excel automation as the same can be achieved with Excel VBA scripting?

Tags: blueprism, rpa, uipath

**Do we really need RPA for Excel automation as the same can be achieved with Excel VBA scripting ?**

MS Excel VBO is just another way of representing the vb code to make it more resuable.
But i assume the same can be done with VB scripting as well.

> What are pros and cons of RPA in regards to Excel Automation ?

Comment: Can you achieve enterprise-grade scalability with Excel VBA out of the box? Is the method for creating Excel VBA accessible to business users (as easy as a flowchart)? Can VBA be easily hooked into other business applications via the applciations' GUIs? Does VBA provide enterprise-grade logging and audit-ability out of the box? There are lots of advantages to RPA over plain old VBA. However, there is a tool for everything, and some are better fits than others for different projects.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very specific. *Any technology has its pros and cons*. Way more important would be the aim that you want to achieve.

If you e.g. just want to use some Excel calculations, go and take **VBA** as you do not have to install any additional tool. Here RPA is pretty much an overkill.

But often you would like to additionally upload that Excel file or send it via mail etc. Here a tool like **UiPath** or **Blueprism** is really helpful.

Also, the VBA is something you need to learn. RPA tools take away those efforts and are able to manage things way easier.

In the case of UiPath for instance, there is a huge community developing things in UiPath Go! There you can take a preset of Excel calculations without any effort.